# File.Exists and File.Copy not working on windows service

Tags: c#, file, file-io, windows-services

I wrote a windows service that is supposed to copy a file from a UNC path to the local hard drive using FileCopy and File.Exists. This service works fine when is not on a UNC path but for some reason when the file that needs to be found and copied is on a UNC path it does not work. I tried exactly the same code on a regular winforms application and the code works with no issues. I am running this service with administrator privileges so I believe this is not a permission issue neither a string path issue since the same code works with no issues on a winform application.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I am sure I have had a similar problem myself but can't remember the details. Can you include some code to give a clearer picture of what is going on?

Comment: Are your paths hardcoded? Plus provide your code in your question please.

Comment: Also provide your error messages if you have any. I suspect a security error.

Comment: Include code and error message if you want help. Does the account you're running the service under have permission to the UNC path (I assume the Winform test you did was running under your credentials, which may account for a difference)?

Comment: Sorry guys I did not add the code since I thought it was not gonna be useful. Here is the code  :

Comment: if(File.Exists(UNCPath + "\\EZConfig.xml"))                                                          { File.Copy(UNCPath + "\\EZConfig.xml", usbDriveLetter + "\\EZConfig.xml",true); }          // UNCPath is \\FMNAS01\Current_Engineering\Photos

Comment: The winforms test was using the same account that the service is installed in. Do you think I need to add permissions in the service as stated in here : http://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/ . I did not get any errors either when I added a try catch statement

Comment: Windows Services are running in the local system account. I don't exactly know what you did to run in as "Administrator" but you won't be able to access network shares as long as the service does not get an alternative logon in windows. So this could be your personal windows account or the network service account. In addition, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622089/windows-service-cant-access-network-share